# Faston/Lucar blade thickness

Tags: connector, dimensions

Does the blade thickness of Lucar/Faston-type connectors vary methodically with both blade width and "colour" i.e. wire rating?

I'm looking at some UPS cells with blades which appear to be 0.75mm thick, and am trying to work out whether these are standard 1/4" "yellows" before ordering anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color usually indicates the cross section size of the wire crimp part. And does not reflect the spade dimensions.

Spade dimension vary per brand. There is no real standard for spade connectors.

0.8 x 6.35mm is a common size, the datasheet should mention the spade size or brand used on the battery.

Comment: I know that the colour doesn't reflect on the blade width (except that the narrowest spades are unlikely to be made in yellow), but it would still be reasonable for spades made for thicker wire (i.e. heavier current) to be physically thicker. My spares drawers only have anonymous reds and yellows ATM, so I'm being cautious.

Comment: I've checked against somebody else's anonymous stash, and that 0.8(ish) mm appears plausible for a yellow.